# Return a Task from a method with type void

Tags: c#, task

I would like to create a task to run serial commands on. At this time I do not need to return anything from the method that is doing the work. This will probably change later, but I am now curious as to how this.

This is what I have. I would like to use a separate method for the task instead of creating an anonymous action. I have tried returning void, with the result of "void can not be explicitly converted to a Task". I have also tried. `Task<void>`. The Last thing I have tried is returning a Task, but I receive, error "Not all Code paths return a value" and "Can not implicily convert void to type task"

[image]

In the pass I have used a Thread to accomplish this, but I'd like to use Tasks this time around.

```
internal class Hardware
{
    private EventHandler<SequenceDoneEventArgs> SequenceDone;

    private List<Step> Steps;
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort comport = null;

    private Task SequenceTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource RequestStopSource;
    private CancellationToken RequestStopToken;


    private void Initialize()
    {
        comport = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM2", 115200, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None,8);
        comport.DataReceived += Comport_DataReceived;
    }

    public async void RunSequence()
    {
        if (comport == null)
        {
            Initialize();
        }
        if (!comport.IsOpen)
        {
            comport.Open();
        }

        RequestStopSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        RequestStopToken = RequestStopSource.Token;

        SequenceTask = await Task.Run(() => { doSequence(); });

    }

    private Task doSequence()
    {
        //** Run Sequence stuff here

    }
}
```

ETA:

In the end this is my the complete solution

```
internal class Hardware
{
    private EventHandler<SequenceDoneEventArgs> SequenceDone;

    private List<Step> Steps;
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort comport = null;

    private Task SequenceTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource RequestStopSource;
    private CancellationToken RequestStopToken;


    private void Initialize()
    {
        comport = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM2", 115200, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None,8);
        comport.DataReceived += Comport_DataReceived;
    }

    public async void RunSequence()
    {
        if (comport == null)
        {
            Initialize();
        }
        if (!comport.IsOpen)
        {
            comport.Open();
        }

        RequestStopSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        RequestStopToken = RequestStopSource.Token;

        SequenceTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { await doSequence(); });

    }

    private Task doSequence()
    {
        //** Run Sequence stuff here

        //return null;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: just return `Task`?

Comment: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: The Last thing I have tried is returning a Task, but I don't know how to generate a Simple new Task. It seems you need to assign an action to it on when I call the constructor. So how do I do that?

Comment: what constructor? what action? what is a "simple new task"? If a Task does not have a "return value" it is just a Task. If you want to return something you use generics i.e. Task<T>. You dont *have* to though. Could you explain why using `Task` is incorrect?

Comment: Are you looking for `Task.FromResult()`?

Comment: Question Updated with screen shot

Comment: Task.FromResult() doesnt work on actions that are void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SequenceTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async() => { await doSequence(); });
```

Also your `RunSequence()` should return `Task` instead of `void`.

Actually if you await the `Task` this should result in the same:

```
SequenceTask = await doSequence();
```

Comment: This got be the closest. In the end I needed to do `SequenceTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { await doSequence(); });`

Comment: Task.Run() is kinder to kittens

Answer (score 6):

Just mark `doSequence` as `async` (assuming it uses `await`):

```
private async Task doSequence()
```

Also, it's a good idea to return this `Task` in the delegate you pass to `Task.Run`:

```
SequenceTask = await Task.Run(() => doSequence());
```

> I would like to create a task to run serial commands on.

This leads me to believe that using `async` and `Task` may not be the best solution for your scenario. I suggest you look into TPL Dataflow.